# Speedy answer vs elaborate answer

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, accepted-answer

Consider the following question I've just had answered:

[Equivalent of FindControl() for use with <li>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19769411/equivalent-of-findcontrol-for-use-with-li#19769547)

Which would be the correct answer to mark as accepted?

The shorter answer was given first (in the comments) (let's also assume as a hypothetical, second case scenario that it was posted as an answer first). The more elaborate, in-depth answer was posted shortly after.

Does the more thorough answer get accepted? Or could it merely be adding extra noise to what the shorter answer has suggested? Or is this subjective?

Comment: Unless one is a direct copy of the other ignore answer times when deciding which is better. Although ultimately its up to you

Comment: That is totally up the the asker.

Answer (score 5):

That is totally up the the asker.

There is no rule a OP has to follow when accepting an answer. Normally a OP chooses the most helpful answer. What aspects that include can be very different to someone.